# Get substring using /f delims and still keep all delimiter characters

Tags: batch-file, substring, delimiter

I have to use batch to extract a substring from a string. I googled a bit seems like using /f delims is the way to go, but i'm stuck, delims is also stripping all the delimiter character (= ;) in the string.

```
SET STRING={"Building":{"type":"String","value":"Suite=123:638.way;PC=777;Contact Number=019553;"}}
FOR /f "tokens=4,5 delims=:" %%a in ("%STRING%") do (
  set SUBSTRG=%%a
  set SUBSTRG2=%%b
)
echo %SUBSTRG% %SUBSTRG2%
```

I want to extract the substring ""Suite=123:638.way;PC=777;Contact Number=019553;" from STRING. But using the delims as stated in the code, I ended up with
`"Suite 123638.way PC 777 Contact Number 019553 "}}`
I have very little knowledge in batch command, how can i fix this? Is there a better way than use /f delims?

Comment: *Environment variable substitution has been enhanced as follows:

    %PATH:str1=str2%

would expand the PATH environment variable, substituting each occurrence
of "str1" in the expanded result with "str2".  "str2" can be the empty
string to effectively delete all occurrences of "str1" from the expanded
output.  "str1" can begin with an asterisk, in which case it will match
everything from the beginning of the expanded output to the first
occurrence of the remaining portion of str1*.
 From `set /?`. This allows you to chop your string up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I wouldn't use a `for /f` loop for this.  I'm a firm believer in using a parser that understands the structure when scraping any sort of structured data -- an XML parser for XML data, JSON parser for JSON data, and so on.  So I would be more likely to use PowerShell or JScript for this than pure Batch.  Here's an example Batch + PowerShell hybrid script that demonstrates:

```js
<# : batch portion
@echo off & setlocal

set JSON={"Building":{"type":"String","value":"Suite=123:638.way;PC=777;Contact Number=019553;"}}

for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"'
) do set "value=%%~I"

echo Scraped value: %value%
exit /b

: end Batch / begin PowerShell #>
add-type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
$JSON = new-object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$obj = $JSON.DeserializeObject($env:JSON)
$obj.Building.value
```

This sort of method will be more resilient to spacing anomalies, variable order, etc, since you're retrieving the "value" value by object hierarchy rather than as flat text.

If you prefer a pure Batch solution, I would use variable substring substitution to trim away the unwanted parts:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

set JSON={"Building":{"type":"String","value":"Suite=123:638.way;PC=777;Contact Number=019553;"}}

rem // Step 1: Strip everything before and including value":"
set "str=%JSON:*value":"=%"

rem // Step 2: Strip everything after and including the next quotation mark
set str=%str:"=&rem;%

rem // Step 3: output result
echo Scraped value: %str%
```

It's simpler and very efficient, but it's also heavily dependent upon your data predictably maintaining the same order and spacing.  It's more fragile than using a JSON parser.

Comment: This is of great help! the pure batch methods work very well in my situation as the string is pretty consistent. But thx for showing me the hybrid version as well i tried it and learned alot.